# Is it normal for a husky to shed large patches of fur in the summer?

Tags: dogs, shedding, husky

The pictures I have are too large to upload but there are large patches of fur shedding to the point where there is just thin short hair left. Brought her to the vet today and they said there was likely nothing wrong since she isn't itching and there are no sores on her skin. Is this kind of shedding normal for a husky? We are used to her shedding but it's never been this much before.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly normal, Huskies (among) are double coated dogs. Breeds like German Shepherds, Akitas, Malamutes, Newfoundlands etc also have them, mainly working dogs bread for harsh working conditions.

This means there is an additional coat you don't normally see, unless you go looking, it is shorter than the common white/grey/black coat you see, this is what youre seeing remaining when your dogs fur is falling out.

Double coated dogs shed the longer outer coat leaving the undercoat. It is common to see large amounts of hair fall out with ease in the summer.

I recommend brushing your dog a few times a week it will remove dead hairs and make your dog feel very comfortable.

Here is some additional reading:

https://www.petguide.com/petcare/dog/what-is-a-double-coated-dog/

Answer (score 0):

I would believe so. Huskies are used to cold weather so the hot weather would result in them losing the hair to cool off. And if the vet says its nothing to worry about, then I really wouldnt

Answer (score 0):

This is the husky "blowing" their coat.  Twice a year (spring + fall) they go through a more serious fur regeneration effort that can create these tufts of fur.

Frequent and thorough brushing during this period is the way to keep your house clean.